# How to make a PhysicsBody based on Alpha Values

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics, terrain, code-structure

Suppose there there is a scene as follows:
There is a scene with the same size as the frame of the device. The scene has a red ball, which is able to move throughout the 'world'. This world is defined by black and white areas, where the ball is ONLY able to move in the area that is white. Here is a picture to help explain:
[image: Picture of the scene]

Parts of the black area can be erased, as if the user is drawing with white color over the scene. This would mean that the area in which the ball can be moved is constantly changing. Now, how would one go about implementing a physicsBody for the an edge between the white and black areas?

I tried redefining the physicsBody every time it is changed, but once the shape becomes complex enough, this isn't a viable solution at all. I tried creating a two-dimensional array of 'boxes' that are invisible and specify whether most of the area within each box is white or black, and if the ball touched a box that was black, it would be pushed back. However, this required heavy rendering and iterating over the array too much. Since my original array contained boxes a little bigger than a pixel, I tried making these boxes bigger to smooth the motion a little, but this eventually caused part of the ball to be stopped by white areas and appear to be inside the black area. This was undesired, since the user could feel invisible barriers that they seemed to be hitting.

I tried searching for other methods to implement this 'destructible terrain' type scene, but the solutions that I found and tried were using other game engines. To further clarify, I am using Objective-C and Apple's SpriteKit framework; and I am not looking for a detailed class full of code, but rather some pseudo-code or implementation ideas that would lead me to a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Essentially you need a contour-tracing algorithm that creates a CGPath of the cave outline. Every time the cave changes, you need to re-run this algorithm and replace the existing edge-loop body. However this tracing and recreating shapes probably prohibits using this in a realtime action game or where the cave may change practically all the time.

Comment: Im sorry if I wasn't clear enough, this was the first solution that I attempted. It was feasible at first (where the cave started with a small white circle); but as you said, it was useless once the edge became a complex shape due to constant change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your deployment target is iOS 8, this may be what you're looking for...

```
+ bodyWithTexture:alphaThreshold:size:
```

Here's a description from Apple's documentation

> Creates a physics body from the contents of a texture. Only texels
>   that exceed a certain transparency value are included in the physics
>   body.

where a texel is a texture element. You will need to convert an image to the texture before creating the `SKPhysicsBody`.

I'm not sure if it will allow for a hole in the middle like your drawing. If not, I suspect you can connect two physics bodies, a left half and a right half, to form the hole.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome idea, I did not know that iOS 8 had this capability. My original idea was, in fact, to have a hole inside of the body (or many different holes, for that matter). I'm thinking of breaking up my texture into many parts, and then using each part as a separate body (to be able to implement the holes). However, if a hole is small enough, it still wont render it. Any idea how I could implement a 'hole' without the multiple textures?

Comment: I personally would target iOS 8 for this type of game. It would take a lot more effort to implement it, and I would guess the physics bodies would only be a rough approximation of the shapes the user will be able to draw.

Comment: The target IS iOS8, i never said otherwise. But if there is a hole in the middle of the texture spritekit wont recognize it

Comment: That's why I suggested splitting the shape into two parts. Why do you need multiple parts?

Comment: The shape would constantly change. If there is a whole inside one of the parts, what then?

Comment: I'm assuming the game starts off with a fairly large hole in the middle with the ball in the center. If the user creates a hole that is not part of the original hole, can the ball interact with the hole? If not, why do you need to create a physics body for non-contiguous hole(s)?

Comment: Your assumption is correct, i would like to recreate a more complex situation where a user would be able to interact with a whole that is essentially unreachable

Comment: How would the user interact with the unreachable holes?

Comment: E.g., teleporting to it

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer, since it technically does answer my OP. I will, however, ask a new question about splitting the physics body ~ hopefully you can throw in some insight! Thanks again